# Nasty sound on truck

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, noise, silverado

My truck is making this horrendous sound whenever my wheels are turning. It’s like a low pitched grinding sound. I’m going to link a video of it so you can hear for yourself. I don’t know anything about cars but my assumption was that my calipers are gumming up and I have ceramic brake pads so that’s why it’s making that sound. I changed my brake pads 2-3 years ago and remember that my calipers were sticking. I also pull a big trailer so they get a heavy use.

https://youtube.com/shorts/e_fS_L5NNN0?feature=share

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You're going to have to help us out here. Please edit your question and include the following: What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission of the truck? Is the noise constant or does it change with speed? What part of the truck is the noise coming from (engine, transmission, differential, front, back)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it’s a 2004 Chevy Silverado 2500 HD with a 6.0 engine. It is gas, I don’t know what type of trans it has. The noise is constant and I can only hear it when going by buildings or other parked cars and going 0-30 miles and hour because anything faster than that my truck blocks out the sound

Comment: I can't discern what noise you might be talking about via the video. Does it go away or change pitch when you apply the brakes?